# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 63-64: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\USER.DESKTOP-PHII7LU\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\USER.DESKTOP-PHII7LU\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

When I run this file, I get this error.

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 63-64: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Any fix for it please